# Find a sorted subsequence of size 4 in an array in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

We are given an array of numbers and we want to find a subsequence of size 4 that is sorted in increasing order.

```
for eg ARRAY                :  -4 2 8 3 1 5
sorted subsequence of size 4 : -4 2 3 5
```

PS:There is a way of finding the sorted subsequence of size 3([see this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-sorted-subsequence-of-size-3-in-linear-time/)). I am trying to think along the same lines but can't seem to find a solution for 4 integers.

Comment: There might not be an increasing subsequence that long. Consider the sequence 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, it has no [non-trivial] increasing subsequences

Comment: Though Erdős and Szekeres proved there is a monotonic (increasing or decreasing) subsequence length at least sqrt(n).

Comment: @colonelPanic you can assume that there exists such a sequence.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a solution that will find a sorted subsequence of fixed size `k+1` by doing `k` passes over the input. Each pass is done left-to-right.

Pass 1: Create an auxiliary array `p1[0..n-1]`. `p1[i]` should store the index `j` of a number which is smaller than `arr[i]` and is on the left side of `arr[i]` (in other words: `j<i` and `arr[j]<arr[i]`). `p1[i]` should contain -1 if there is no such element. (`p1` is the same as the `smaller` array from the solution for size 3).

Pass 2: Create an auxiliary array `p2[0..n-1]`. `p2[i]` should store the index `j` of a number which is smaller than `arr[i]`, is on the left side of `arr[i]`, and such that `p1[j] != -1` (in other words: `j<i`, `arr[j]<arr[i]`, and `p1[j]!=-1`). `p2[i]` should contain -1 if there is no such element.

....

Pass k: Create an auxiliary array `pk[0..n-1]`. `pk[i]` should store the index `j` of a number which is smaller than `arr[i]`, is on the left side of `arr[i]`, and such that `p(k-1)[j] != -1` (in other words: `j<i`, `arr[j]<arr[i]`, and `p(k-1)[j]!=-1`). `pk[i]` should contain -1 if there is no such element.

After the `k`th pass, each element where `pk[i] != -1` corresponds to the largest element in a sorted subsequence of size `k+1`.

Pseudocode for `k`th pass (k>1):

```
function do_kth_pass(pk[], p_k_minus_1[])
    min = -1
    for i in 0..n-1:
        if min != -1 and arr[i] > arr[min]:
            pk[i] = min
        else
            pk[i] = -1
        if p_k_minus_1[i] != -1 and (min == -1 or arr[i] < arr[min]):
            min = i
```

Example:

```
Index:   0  1  2  3  4  5
Array:  -4  2  8  3  1  5
p1:     -1  0  0  0  0  0
p2:     -1 -1  1  1 -1  4
p3:     -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  3
```

After 3 passes, you have p3[5] != -1, so a sorted subsequence of size 4 exists. The indices of its elements are: `p1[p2[p3[5]]], p2[p3[5]], p3[5], 5` which is 0,1,3,5

Comment: I think the last if in the for loop must have been

if(p_k_minus_1[i]!=-1) && (min==-1 || arr[i]<arr[min])){
min = i;
}

Comment: can you explain it how the first pass is calculated ? and the second pass ?

Comment: nice algorithm... kudos

Answer (score 4):

Having a greater and lesser array is a good option but it increases the space complexity. Below, is a solution to find four numbers in a linear subsequence without additional array space but rather it uses constant space and does only one pass over the array.

```
#include <iostream>

void sortedSubseqFour(int a[], int n)
{
    int small = INT_MAX;
    int middle_1 = INT_MAX;
    int middle_2 = INT_MAX; 
    int greater = 0;

    int main_small = 0;
    int main_middle_1 = 0;

    int main_main_small = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] <= small)
            small = a[i];
        else if (a[i] <= middle_1)
        {
            middle_1 = a[i];
            main_small = small;
        }
        else if (a[i] <= middle_2)
        {
            middle_2 = a[i];
            main_middle_1 = middle_1;
            main_main_small = main_small;
        }
        else
        {
            greater = a[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    //end of loop

    if (greater != 0)
        std::cout << main_main_small << '\t' << main_middle_1 << '\t'
                  << middle_2 << '\t' << greater;
    else
        std::cout << "No such Quadruple";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {6, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 0, 7, 2, 11};
    int n = 10; 

    sortedSubseqFour(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

The above approach remembers all layers of minimum's when it sets the current minimum. The same code can also be used for a sorted subsequence of size `3` in an array by removing `main_main_small` and `middle_2` part of the code.

If, the same code is to be extended up to size `k` then at say minimum `i`, we have to remember all minimum's before `i`, i.e `min_1`, `min_2`,... till `min_i`. Only in the last minimum, i.e. the greatest value in our subsequence, we just break and there is no need to remember previous or current minimum.

Please do inform if any bugs are discovered!

Comment: 1) Condition `greater != 0` is wrong: `a[i]` that is assigned to `greater` can itself be zero. 2) I suggest you rename the variables used in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the longest increasing subsequence and see if its size if greater than equal to 4(or even k in case you need to find it for a more general question). If the length of the Longest Increasing Subsequence is less than 4(or k) you can report that no such subsequence exists. LIS can be found out in `O(nlog(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `smaller` and `greater` array, similarly as to what was done for a subsequence of size 3. In addition to this, also have `betweenSmallerAndCurrent` array which stores the index of a value that is between the smallest and the current element - both in value and in index. More explicitly:

```
betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] = -1 or

input[smaller[i]] < input[betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]] < input[value[i]] and
smaller[i] < betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] < value[i]
```

Constructing this should be pretty easy.

You'd just return the index `i` where `betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]`, `smaller[betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]]` and `greater[i]` are all initialized. Note that we can't simply check `smaller[i]` as we may have something like `[2,3,1,4,5]`, in which case, when we get to `4`, the second smallest value `3` is before the current smallest value `1`.

**Example:**

```
Indices: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
Input:   12 11 10 5  6  2  9  30

smaller: -1 -1 -1 -1 3  -1 5  5
betweenSmallerAndCurrent: 
         -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 4  4

greater: 7  7  7  7  7  7  7  -1
```

The only index with all values initialized is 6 (input value 9).

**Java code:** (not extensively tested)

```
void find4Numbers(int arr[], int n)
{
   int max = n-1; //Index of maximum element from right side
   int min = 0, second = -1; //Index of minimum element from left side
   int i;

   // Create an array that will store index of a smaller
   // element on left side. If there is no smaller element
   // on left side, then smaller[i] will be -1.
   int[] smaller = new int[n];
   int[] betweenSmallerAndCurrent = new int[n];
   smaller[0] = -1;  // first entry will always be -1
   betweenSmallerAndCurrent[0] = -1;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (arr[i] <= arr[min])
       {
          min = i;
          smaller[i] = -1;
          betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] = -1;
       }
       else
       {
          smaller[i] = min;
          if (second != -1 && arr[second] < arr[i])
             betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] = second;
          else 
             betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] = -1;
          if (second == -1 || arr[i] < arr[second])
             second = i;
       }
   }

   // Create another array that will store index of a
   // greater element on right side. If there is no greater
   // element on right side, then greater[i] will be -1.
   int[] greater = new int[n];
   greater[n-1] = -1;  // last entry will always be -1
   for (i = n-2; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       if (arr[i] >= arr[max])
       {
          max = i;
          greater[i] = -1;
       }
       else
          greater[i] = max;
   }

   // Make sure they're right
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smaller));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(betweenSmallerAndCurrent));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(greater));

   // Now find a number which has both a greater number on
   // right side and smaller number on left side
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i] != -1 && smaller[betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]] != -1 && greater[i] != -1)
       {
          System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d\n",
                            arr[smaller[betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]]],
                            arr[betweenSmallerAndCurrent[i]],
                            arr[i],
                            arr[greater[i]]);
          return;
       }
   }

   // If we reach number, then there are no such 3 numbers
   System.out.println("No such triplet found");
}
```

You may notice that the main code changes from [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-sorted-subsequence-of-size-3-in-linear-time/), apart from the C to Java conversion and added initializations, lies in the loop that sets up `smaller`. The code should be pretty easy to understand - try translating it into words if you're having trouble.

[Test](https://ideone.com/DZDyBA).

Answer (score 0):

For each element, find next greater element index else -1
Now think of this as a graph and find a path of length k(if it exist)
This can be done easily in linear time using hashtable and memoization.